# Setting the edit text value programmatically, android?

Tags: android

I'm very new to android and I have an `editText` in which I wish to set up the current mobile number of that device if presents else leave as such.

I know I can get the current mobile number this way:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = tm.getLine1Number();
```

But how do I *say* to android so that it can set the `editText` field to the current mobile number?

Answer (score 3):

First, find your `EditText` by its id:

```
 EditText <YourEditText> = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.<YourEditTextID>);

<YourEditText>.setText(number);  //your String
```